# in blender, using python, how to read multilayer exr, edit several layers, then resave to multilayer exr?

Tags: python, openexr

blender doesn't allow access to the pixels of image blocks that have a multilayer exr loaded.  How can I read a multilayer exr, edit several layers, then resave to multilayer exr.

I'm unable to build any modules on user machines such as OpenEXR, the solution has to be purely python.  Something like minexr but for writing and also with compatibility with zip compression.